# Sci-fi from the 60's where population was controlled by using shares

Tags: story-identification

I heard about this sci-fi book or maybe short story second-hand and it's intrigued me that population could be controlled by providing a limited number of shares for babies that could be bought or sold on a stock market.  Not the babies, of course, but the permission to have them.  Anyone recognize this?

Comment: Not even remotely a match, but the title brought to mind the much more recent *[The Unincorperated Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unincorporated_Man)* which posits a future in which shares of people could be bought much like you can buy shares of a public company. As you can guess from the title a disruptive influence appears.

Answer (score 5):

Some elements are similar to Larry Niven's Known Space series.  Each person has the right to have one child, but additional 'birthrights' can be bought or earned.

From [larryniven.net](http://news.larryniven.net/concordance/main.asp?alpha=F):

> A subsection of the UN which enforced the Fertility Laws on Earth (but
>   not elsewhere), including compulsory birth control strictly limiting
>   population, which resulted in Earth's population being stabilized at
>   18 billion in the mid-21st century. The Fertility Board granted the
>   birthright, specifying the number of children any individual was
>   allowed. Most couples were granted two children, but some were denied
>   any and some were granted more, based on genetic desirability. A
>   scandal in 2650 resulted in drastic changes: every person had the
>   right to one child; second and third birthrights could come
>   automatically for such things as high IQ, useful psychic powers, or
>   survival traits such as natural longevity or perfect teeth;
>   birthrights could be purchased at one million stars apiece; and the
>   Birthright Lottery was created. One could also fight (to the death)
>   for birthrights in the arena. The most important function of the ARM
>   was enforcement of the Fertility Laws.

[Spoiler alert: Ringworld]

> Puppeteers manipulated members of the Fertility Board, with bribery
>  and blackmail, causing a scandal and the creation of the Birthright
>  Lottery. During the First Ringworld Expedition in 2851, Nessus claimed
>  Puppeteers wanted to make Humans luckier. See also birth control.

Reference: "ARM", "The Ethics of Madness", "The Warriors", "Grendel",
Ringworld chs. 2, 5, 8, 13-14, 20

Answer (score 2):

In Kim Stanley Robinson's [*Green Mars,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553572393) the second book of her [*Red Mars*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QCS914) trilogy, a character proposes something like this during a game.

*Green mars,* Part II, Ch. 6:

> And they did, rather subdued. They played Population Reduction, and
>   given the alternative they had just contemplated, went at it with a
>   certain intensity. Each of them took a turn being Emperor of the
>   World, as Fort put it, and outlined his or her plan in some
>   detail.
>  When it was Art’s turn, he said, “I would give everyone
>   alive a birthright which entitled them to parent three-quarters of a
>   child.”
>  Everyone laughed, including Fort. But Art persevered. He
>   explained that every pair of parents would thus have the right to bear
>   a child and a half; after having one, they could either sell the right
>   to the other half, or arrange to buy a half from some other couple and
>   go on to have a second child. Prices for half children would fluctuate
>   in classic supply/demand fashion. Social consequences would be
>   positive; people who wanted extra children would have to sacrifice for
>   them, and those who didn’t would have a source of income to help
>   support the one they had. When populations dropped far enough, the
>   World Emperor might consider changing the birthright to one child per
>   person, which would be close to a demographic steady state; but given
>   the longevity treatment, the three-quarters limit might have to be in
>   effect for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Ringworld is the right era, but the story line in Green Mars sounds very close, including prices fluctuating in supply/demand fashion.  However, this book was published twenty years after I first heard the idea, so I'm still wondering if there is an earlier book by this or another author. The only other details my friend recalls were that, like Green Mars, the idea was not a main focus of the book, and women were given 1.5 shares (not men) and needed to be in a long-term relationship to get permission to reverse their sterilization.